# Dummy variable for level measurement

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, mathematical-statistics, categorical-data

I'm looking at the PH level in a lake (x) and the number of fishes (y). If the PH level goes below a certain level, say 4.5, the severity for the fishes theoretically increases.

Model: $y=\beta+\alpha*x+Dummy_{x<4.5}$

Question: Is it okay to include a dummy variable for a variable (x) and the actual variable itself as in the regression above? Note: the example is indeed just an example.

Comment: What is the "severity of the fishes"? I'm sorry, but it's burning curiosity.

Comment: its just an example, nothing else im sorry. Its just that I need to know that the model above is fine if I have a theoretical level where the dynamics change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you also fitted a coefficient for the dummy variable, the model you described would be:

$$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x + \beta_2\mathbb{1}_{x < 4.5} + \epsilon$$

Assuming the fitted model has $\beta_2\neq 0$, this would model the relationship between $x$ and $y$ as being discontinuous. For instance, if you had $\beta_0 = \beta_1 = 1$ and $\beta_2 = -1$, then the fitted value for $x = 4.5$ would be 5.5 while the fitted value for $x = 4.5-\delta$ for arbitrarily small $\delta > 0$ would be $4.5-\delta$.

In most applications such discontinuities don't make sense, as an infinitesimal change in $x$ would be expected to yield an infinitesimal change in the fitted value of $y$.

You might consider instead using [segmented regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmented_regression), which models $y$ as a piecewise linear function of $x$. Then you could have a different slope for the relationship between $y$ and $x$ in the region where $x < 4.5$ and the region where $x \geq 4.5$ but you could have a continuous relationship between the two variables. Segmented regression is implemented in R in the [segmented package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/segmented/segmented.pdf).

Comment: interesting. but if $\beta_2$ is not zero (on e.g. 5% significance level) doesnt that imply that there might be an actual discontinous change?

Furthermore If i understand correctly it can be fine in (maybe) some applications ? for example what if we know that the reproduction level of fishes for example is reduced alot after 4.5 PH. Wouldnt that imply that the dummy might work?

Comment: @ParashDejmar Statistically significant coefficient values do not imply your model is structurally accurate. Though I don't know much about the relationship between PH and fish count, I would not expect the number of fish to decrease by 19% when the PH decreased from 4.5 to 4.499999999.